# How to get both comments and their replies from Instagram API in one query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I am using the below given URL for GET request -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/${ig_media.id}/comments?access_token=${config.userAccessToken}
```

But it's returning only comments on Instagram media, can I get both comments and their replies in one query? As I don't want to do query for each comment to get replies.

Comment: Should probably work using Field Expansion syntax. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/field-expansion#nested-requests

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am late, but maybe some newcomers will need this information.

Your query is fine, all you need is to add Query params to define the fields you  need like this :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/${ig_media.id}/comments?fields=id,from,replies,text&access_token=${config.userAccessToken}
```